# Is it possible to find value of $~\cos 180^{\circ}~$ and $~\cos 360^{\circ}~$ with the reference angle method?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm confused as to which quadrant $~+180^{\circ}~$ and $~+360^{\circ}~$  lie in.

If I'm able to determine this and their reference angles then I will be able to assign a positive or negative sign to the values of $~\cos 180^{\circ}~$  and $~\cos 360^{\circ}~$ .

Or is there another approach to this?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I'm in an examination and I can't draw this graph?

Comment: Pick one of the appropriate quadrants and stick with it. If you follow whatever steps consistently for one quadrant or the other, it should work. (But, these particular cosines should be really easy, right?)

Comment: Which quadrant does $0^\circ$ lie in, if any? $+360^\circ$ could then be in the same quadrant and $+180^\circ$ in the opposite quadrant

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the unit circle approach?

Since $180^{\circ}$ terminates in standard position at the point $(-1,0)$, $~\cos 180^{\circ}~ = -1$. Similarly,  $~\cos 360^{\circ}~ = 1$ as $360^{\circ}$ terminates at $(1,0)$ in standard position.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an image of the function $$y=\cos(x)$$ with the period $2\pi$ then we get $$\cos(180^{\circ})=-1$$ and $$\cos(360^{\circ})=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$~+180^{\circ}~$ lies in the negative $~X~$ axis  and $~+ 360^{\circ}~$  lies on the  positive $~X~$ axis.

See the picture

[image]

In this connection  I would like to mention that we take angle $~\theta~$  in anti-clock wise direction.

So we can write

$1.\quad~\theta=+0^{\circ}~$ along positive $~X~$ axis (i.e., along $~OX~$)

$2.\quad~\theta=+90^{\circ}~$ along positive $~Y~$ axis (i.e., along $~OY~$)

$3.\quad~\theta=+180^{\circ}~$ along negative $~X~$ axis (i.e., along $~-OX~$)

$4.\quad~\theta=+270^{\circ}~$ along negative $~Y~$ axis (i.e., along $~-OY~$)

$5.\quad~\theta=+360^{\circ}~$ along positive $~X~$ axis (i.e., along $~OX~$)

and so on.

Similarly,

$1.\quad~\theta=-0^{\circ}~$ along positive $~X~$ axis (i.e., along $~OX~$)

$2.\quad~\theta=-90^{\circ}~$ along negative $~Y~$ axis (i.e., along $~-OY~$)

$3.\quad~\theta=-180^{\circ}~$ along negative $~X~$ axis (i.e., along $~-OX~$)

$4.\quad~\theta=-270^{\circ}~$ along positive $~Y~$ axis (i.e., along $~OY~$)

$5.\quad~\theta=-360^{\circ}~$ along positive $~X~$ axis (i.e., along $~OX~$)

and so on.

---

From the picture you can conclude that $~\cos 180^{\circ}~=~-1~$ and $~\cos 360^{\circ}~=~1~$

Answer (score 0):

For $180^{\circ}$ as well as $360^{\circ}$ in order to evaluate $ \cos \theta $ consider absolute value ratio of x-axis projection and unit radius vector  $1$  when it rotates..without regard to sign at first.

Next,

there is no ambiguity in settling the sign of either case. Because

for $180^{\circ}$ cosine is negative in neighboring second and third quadrants anyhow.

And,

for $360^{\circ}$ cosine is positive in neighboring first and fourth quadrants anyhow.

So  $ \cos 180^{\circ} =-1 $ and $ \cos 360^{\circ} =+1. $